# Unexpected character '#' in LinearGradient

Tags: react-native, vue.js, linear-gradients, vue-native

I want add a `LinearGradient` in `vue native` but getting this error with the following code

```
<template>
    <View >
      <linear-gradient :colors="['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']">
         <text class="loginWording">login</text> 
      </linear-gradient>
    </View>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need pass colors as array of string

```
<LinearGradient colors={["#4c669f", "#3b5998", "#192f6a"]}>
   <view class="login">
     <text class="loginWording">login</text> 
   </view>
</LinearGradient>
```

Comment: added your code, but now i getting 
`invariant violation: text string must be rendered within a <Text> component`

Comment: Your `<text>` component is lowercase, the valid text component is `<Text/>` https://reactnative.dev/docs/text

Comment: I changed to `<Text>` but still getting the same error

Comment: because I'm using `vue native`?

Comment: double check, that error indicating you are trying to render plain text outside `<Text/>` component

Comment: I already posted the whole code, and I really cannot find any error, but if i remove the `LinearGradient` then it will no error at all

Comment: maybe that library not compatible with vue native, try open issue on github and the author will help you. This is out off topic, i already answer the main question, please ask new question for this

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to write it like so:

```
<linear-gradient :colors="['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']">
   <view class="login">
     <text class="loginWording">login</text> 
   </view>
</linear-gradient>
```

Comment: Ok, so I'm new to Vue native (but quite an expert in Vue.js)  so I decide to install all the requirement packages to run a sample project to help you.
I need a few info from you.

Did you install globally expo? LinearGradient it's a expo component
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient/

Did you follow the installation guide for expo?
https://vue-native.io/docs/installation.html#For-Expo-users